# How to use Async / Await in Python with messaging based invocation

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

After years of NodeJS dev, I decided to give Python a shot. So far so good, but I just ran into a wall that I would really like some help with.

I am working on a library that communicates with a remote machine using MQTT. When invoking a function on that library, a message is posted for processing on that remote machine. Once the processing is done, it posts a new message on the bus that my library picks up on and returns the result back to the calling code (the code that invoked the library function).

In Javascript, this is done by returning a Promise, that has a `resolve` & `reject` function, that can be stored within the library until the remote message comes back through the broker with the result (intercepted in a different function elsewhere in the library), at which point I can simply invoke the 'resolve' function stored previously to return control to the calling code (the code that invoked the async function of my library). This library function would simply be invoked using the `async` keyword.

Now in Python, async/await does not use `resolve` and `reject` functions that can conveniently be stored away for later, so the logic must be implemented differently I suppose. Using a simple callback function rather than an async/await workflow works, but makes in inconvenient when invoked multiple times in sequence for similar back and forth communications, given that each result handling callback is a separate function.

Here is a basic example of what this would look like in Javascript (for illustration only):

```js
let TASKS = {};

....

mqttClient.on('message', (topic, message) => {
    if (topic == "RESULT_OK/123") {
        TASKS["123"].resolve(message);
    } else if (topic == "RESULT_KO/123") {
        TASKS["123"].reject(message);
    }
});

...

let myAsyncLibraryFunction = (someCommand) => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        TASKS["123"] = {
            resolve: res,
            reject: rej
        };
        mqttClient.publish("REQUEST/123", someCommand);
    });
}
```

To call this, I would simply have to do:

```js
try{
    let response1 = await myAsyncLibraryFunction("do this");
    let response2 = await myAsyncLibraryFunction("now do that");
    ...
} catch(e) {
    ...
}
```

NodeJS is an event loop based language, that's why this is very appropriate for those types of use cases. But this type of application logic is common when dealing with message-based disparate backends, so I am sure there are good ways of solving this in Python as well.

This is a test Python code snippet that I am working on, that attempts to use a `future` object to achieve something similar:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import asyncio
import threading

# Init a new asyncio event loop
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

# define a global future placeholder
_future = None

# Create MQTT client
mqttClient = mqtt.Client()

# MQTT Event - on connect
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected")
    client.subscribe("YAVA/#")
    
    # We start a new thread to test our workflow.
    #
    # If I had done this on the current thread, then the MQTT event loop 
    # would get stuck (does not process incoming and outgoing messages anymore) when 
    # calling "await" on the future object later on.
    taskThread = threading.Thread(target=_simulateClient, args=())
    taskThread.start()

# MQTT Event - on incoming message
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    
    global _future
    if msg.topic.startswith("YAVA/API/TASK_DONE/") == True:
        payload = str(msg.payload.decode("utf-8", "ignore"))
        # Resolve the future object
        _future.set_result(payload)

mqttClient.on_connect = on_connect
mqttClient.on_message = on_message




# Use asyncio to call a async function and test the workflow
def _simulateClient():
    asyncio.run(performAsyncTask())

# This async function will ask for a task to be performed on a remote machine, 
# and wait for the response to be sent back
async def performAsyncTask():
    result = await pubAndWhaitForResponse("YAVA/API/TASK_START", "")
    print(result)
    
# perform the actual MQTT async logic
async def pubAndWhaitForResponse(topic, message):
    # Create a future object that can be resolved in the MQTT event "on_message"
    global _future
    _future = asyncio.get_running_loop().create_future()

    # Publish message that will start the task execution remotely somewhere
    global mqttClient
    mqttClient.publish(topic, message)

    # Now block the thread until the future get's resolved
    result = await _future

    # Return the result
    return result


# Start the broker and loop^forever in the main thread
mqttClient.connect("192.168.1.70", 1883, 60)
# The MQTT library will start a new thread that will continuously 
# process outgoing and incoming messages through that separate thread.
# The main thread will be blocked so that the program does not exit
mqttClient.loop_forever()
```

It all runs fine, but the `_future.set_result(payload)` line does not seem to resolve the future. I never see the result printed.

It feels like there is not much missing to get this sorted. Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Not getting much feedback so far. I investigated threads and played around with the asyncio library, but with no success. Any ideas would be appreciated...

Comment: Did you take a look at the [`asyncio.Futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html) module which provide `Future` class which should be similar to the JS's `Promises` (I suppose). However, it is part of the "low-level" `asyncio` API, and you would probably bet on the [awaitable tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#awaitables).

Comment: Thanks @AlexisBRENON, I had a look at asyncio.Futures, which indeed looks promising. Unfortunately, I ran into another problem when publishing the request to MQTT, then awaiting the future. The await is a blocking process (which is what I am looking for), but it prevents the MQTT client from actually pushing out the payload. I tried publishing in a separate thread, but that results in a deadlock since the MQTT client is single-threaded only. In other words, I can only publish messages in the thread that instantiated the MQTT client, therefore blocking that thread with await is not working.

Comment: Maybe you can edit your questions with your new insights (giving us some code to experiment). I don't really understand why you encounter a deadlock, and I would like to help you to debug this.

Comment: @AlexisBRENON, I edited the question with a test code sample to show how far I got. I actually managed to get past the thread issue by creating this test code for the post (never a good idea to take code from language A, and translate it directly into language B, especially when A is an event loop based engine, and B is object-oriented...). Now, I am stuck at the future resolution part.

Comment: A post about JS Promises vs. async/await Python: https://quentin.pradet.me/blog/you-dont-need-promises-in-python-just-use-asyncawait.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we are using the `asyncio` library the bad way, mixing it with multi-process/multi-threading parallelism.

Here is an implementation based on the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module. When submitting a task for your remote, your library can return a [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) that the caller can use with the `get()` method: it return the value if available, else it suspend the thread, waiting for the value. Hence, the `Queue` acts as a [Scala's Future](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#futures) or a [JS Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

```py
import multiprocessing
import time
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor

import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format="%(asctime)s ## %(thread)d ## %(funcName)s ## %(message)s")


def remote_on_connect(client, *_):
    logging.info("Connected")
    client.subscribe("YAVA/API/TASK_START")

def remote_on_message(client, _, _1):
    logging.info("Remotely processing your data")
    time.sleep(1)
    logging.info("Publishing result")
    client.publish("YAVA/API/TASK_DONE", 42)


class Lib:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = mqtt.Client()
        self.executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)

        self.client.on_connect = Lib.on_connect
        self.client.connect("test.mosquitto.org")
        self.client.loop_start()

    def stop(self):
        self.client.loop_stop()

    def execute(self):
        cb, queue = self.get_cb()
        self.client.on_message = cb
        self.client.publish("YAVA/API/TASK_START", "foo")
        return queue

    @staticmethod
    def on_connect(client, *_):
        logging.info("Connected")
        client.subscribe("YAVA/API/TASK_DONE")

    def get_cb(self):
        queue = multiprocessing.Queue(maxsize=1)
        def cb(_0, _1, msg):
            self.client.on_message = None
            logging.info("Fetching back the result")
            logging.info(str(msg.payload.decode("utf-8", "ignore")))
            queue.put(42)
            logging.info("Queue filled")
        return cb, queue


def main():
    remote_client = mqtt.Client()
    remote_client.on_connect = remote_on_connect
    remote_client.on_message = remote_on_message
    remote_client.connect("test.mosquitto.org")
    remote_client.loop_start()

    lib = Lib()
    future = lib.execute()

    logging.info("Result is:")
    logging.info(future.get())

    remote_client.loop_stop()
    lib.stop()

    logging.info("Exiting")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
2019-11-19 15:08:34,433 ## 139852611577600 ## remote_on_connect ## Connected
2019-11-19 15:08:34,450 ## 139852603184896 ## on_connect ## Connected
2019-11-19 15:08:34,452 ## 139852632065728 ## main ## Result is:
2019-11-19 15:08:34,467 ## 139852611577600 ## remote_on_message ## Remotely processing your data
2019-11-19 15:08:35,469 ## 139852611577600 ## remote_on_message ## Publishing result
2019-11-19 15:08:35,479 ## 139852603184896 ## cb ## Fetching back the result
2019-11-19 15:08:35,479 ## 139852603184896 ## cb ## 42
2019-11-19 15:08:35,480 ## 139852603184896 ## cb ## Queue filled
2019-11-19 15:08:35,480 ## 139852632065728 ## main ## 42
2019-11-19 15:08:36,481 ## 139852632065728 ## main ## Exiting
```

As you can see in the output, the `main` method execute up to the `future.get` method (as show by the `Result is:` line early in the log). Then, processing happen in another thread, until putting a value inside the shared `Queue`. Now the `future.get` returns (because the value is available) and the `main` method proceed to the end.

Hope this can help you to achieve what you want, but any insights about better ways to achieve this, either with `asyncio` or with smaller data structure than `Queue`, are welcome.

Comment: Yep, that works! It is quite elaborate for something I expected to be straight forward, but the important part is that it does its job. Every language has it's pros and cons for sure. I will accept your answer, thanks again @AlexisBRENON

Answer (score 0):

First thing I can see is that you publish in the `YAVA/API/TASK_START` topic while checking that the topic is `YAVA/API/TASK_DONE/` in your `on_message` callback. Hence, your `_future` never gets a result and the `await _future` never returns...

I advice you to add log. Add these lines at the start of your code:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format="%(asctime)s ## %(thread)d ## %(funcName)s ## %(message)s")
```

Then use `logging.info(...)` to trace your execution order.
I added some to your code (as well as changing the condition in `on_message`) and here is the output.

```
2019-11-19 11:37:10,440 ## 140178907485888 ## __init__ ## Using selector: EpollSelector
2019-11-19 11:37:10,478 ## 140178907485888 ## on_connect ## Connected
2019-11-19 11:37:10,478 ## 140178887976704 ## _simulateClient ## Enter simulate client
2019-11-19 11:37:10,479 ## 140178887976704 ## __init__ ## Using selector: EpollSelector
2019-11-19 11:37:10,480 ## 140178887976704 ## performAsyncTask ## Perform async task
2019-11-19 11:37:10,480 ## 140178887976704 ## pubAndWhaitForResponse ## Pub and wait
2019-11-19 11:37:10,481 ## 140178887976704 ## pubAndWhaitForResponse ## Publish
2019-11-19 11:37:10,481 ## 140178887976704 ## pubAndWhaitForResponse ## Await future: <Future pending created at /usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py:391>
2019-11-19 11:37:10,499 ## 140178907485888 ## on_message ## New message
2019-11-19 11:37:10,499 ## 140178907485888 ## on_message ## Topic: YAVA/API/TASK_DONE
2019-11-19 11:37:10,499 ## 140178907485888 ## on_message ## Filling future: <Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7f7df0f5fd10>()] created at /usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py:391>
```

I also added a log after the `_future.set_result(payload)` line, but it never appears. So the `set_result` seems to hang or something like that...

You probably have to dig inside it to know why/where it hangs.

---

### Edit

By the way, you are mixing many concepts: asyncio, threading, and mqtt (with its own loop).
Moreover, the `asyncio.Future` is not thread-safe, I think it's dangerous to use it as you do. While using debugger, to go inside the `set_result` method, I encounter an exception in the mqtt client class:

```
Non-thread-safe operation invoked on an event loop other than the current one
```

It is never reported on stdout/stderr, but you can maybe catch it in the `on_log` callback of your client.

---

### Edit 2

Here is a more Pythonic example of your code. In this one, the `set_result` does not hang (the log just after is displayed) but it is the `await` in the `main`.

```
import asyncio
import time

import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format="%(asctime)s ## %(thread)d ## %(funcName)s ## %(message)s")


def remote_on_connect(client, *_):
    logging.info("Connected")
    client.subscribe("YAVA/API/TASK_START")

def remote_on_message(client, _, _1):
    logging.info("Remotely processing your data")
    time.sleep(1)
    logging.info("Publishing result")
    client.publish("YAVA/API/TASK_DONE", 42)


class Lib:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = mqtt.Client()
        self.client.on_connect = Lib.on_connect
        self.client.on_log = lambda x: logging.info("Log: %s", x)
        self.client.connect("test.mosquitto.org")
        self.client.loop_start()

    def stop(self):
        self.client.loop_stop()

    def execute(self):
        self.client.publish("YAVA/API/TASK_START", "foo")

        cb, fut = Lib.get_cb()
        self.client.on_message = cb
        return fut

    @staticmethod
    def on_connect(client, *_):
        logging.info("Connected")
        client.subscribe("YAVA/API/TASK_DONE")

    @staticmethod
    def get_cb():
        fut = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_future()
        def cb(_0, _1, msg):
            logging.info("Fetching back the result")
            logging.info(str(msg.payload.decode("utf-8", "ignore")))
            fut.set_result(42)
            logging.info("Future updated")
        return cb, fut


async def main():
    remote_client = mqtt.Client()
    remote_client.on_connect = remote_on_connect
    remote_client.on_message = remote_on_message
    remote_client.connect("test.mosquitto.org")
    remote_client.loop_start()

    lib = Lib()
    future = lib.execute()

    logging.info("Result is:")
    await future
    logging.info(future.result())

    remote_client.loop_stop()
    lib.stop()

    logging.info("Exiting")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Thanks @AlexisBRENON, that's very helpful! For clarification (and that was my fault, I should have been more explicit), my code snippet did not include the remote code, but the message to topic `YAVA/API/TASK_DONE` was fired and intercepted by the sample code I provided remotely. That said, I took your sample code and tested it on my side.

Comment: Unfortunately when I run your code (I am using Python 3.7.4), I get the same behavior, the line `await future` never resolves and the following line never prints out the result (42). You can test it by moving the log `logging.info("Result is:")` from above the line `await future` to below it, the log will never show (at least in my environment):

Comment: 14:04:25,724 ## 4760415680 ## __init__ ## Using selector: KqueueSelector  
14:04:25,785 ## 123145409134592 ## remote_on_connect ## Connected  
14:04:25,808 ## 123145414389760 ## on_connect ## Connected  
14:04:25,831 ## 123145409134592 ## remote_on_message ## Remotely processing your data  
14:04:26,834 ## 123145409134592 ## remote_on_message ## Publishing result
14:04:26,866 ## 123145414389760 ## cb ## Fetching back the result
14:04:26,867 ## 123145414389760 ## cb ## 42
14:04:26,867 ## 123145414389760 ## cb ## Future updated

Comment: As you can see the last log is `Future updated`, but no log saying `Result is:`

Comment: @user3742205 Yes I have the same behavior. I'll try a simple example (without MQTT involved) to better grasp the Future behaviors.

Comment: By the way, the documentation says: "Normally **there is no need** to create Future objects at the application level code." We're probably not using the lib the right way